# Is it possible to see what dropboxd is syncing right now?

Tags: linux, dropbox

The dropbox.py script for dropboxd on linux will give current status:

```
$ dropbox.py status 
Syncing (2,656 files remaining)
Uploading 2,656 files...
```

Or status of a specific file or current folder:

```
$ dropbox.py filestatus 
Camera Uploads:     up to date 
Customer Shares:    syncing
```

But is there a way to see what file(s) are actually being transferred right now?

The reason I ask is that dropbox has been stuck for days syncing but isn't progressing.  I suspect it is stuck on some weirdly large or corrupt file, and if I could identify it, I could remove it / ignore it.

Note

```
$ ls -l /proc/7857/fd
```

Where 7857 is the pid of dropbox, no files in the synced path are shown.

Note that requiring the stopping of dropboxd and re-executing with a debugger would not reveal what is being transferred *now*. Stopping and starting the daemon results in re-indexing and re-commencing synchronisation.  This would likely cause a different set of files to be the ones being transferred.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try the suggested tip with the SSL wireshark?

Comment: @tukan No I didn't.  In the best case this would require capturing the initiation of the SSL session to capture the preshared key.  However, modern apps use Diffie Helman key generation, where the preshared key is never on the wire - this requires the app itself to log the keys used.  I doubt very much that dropbox 1) doesn't use DH and 2) has a mode where it logs keys  (see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/decrypting-tls-in-wireshark-when-using-dhe-rsa-ciphersuites/42350#42350)

Comment: We did not understand each other.  I'm not suggesting you should actually crack/hack DH key exchange.  What I have suggested, I don't know what kind of dropbox plan are you using, is to use RSA keys (https://www.dropbox.com/business/app-integrations/RSA).  Then use wireshark to import that key (https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116557) to decrypt the actual traffic with your own key.

Comment: @tukan Please read the first "Point to note" in the second link you provided.  Also note that the RSA link is an authentication mechanism, nothing to do with RSA as used in encryption.

Comment: I have contacted `dropbox.com` support and they are currently investigating it and have to contact their application department to get greater details. Lets wait for the answer.

Comment: Sigh, talking to the support is rather lengthy process.  They did not answer all my questions yet.   Anyways, the key information is currently now **Dropbox does not support the creation of your own private keys.**.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi @tukan Thanks for taking this to dropbox, but unfortunately the idea that you could create local RSA keys and somehow use those to decrypt traffic to dropbox simply isn't possible. There is always a server side key attached to the certificate they present.  The process is different to RSA keys that you are probably familiar with in SSH, and entirely different to the RSA authentication method. It might be that your questions were difficult to answer because of these misunderstandings.

Comment: Well you would not have to create them by yourself.  You could have some CA or dropbox creating them for you and then you could use them.  Well I have ask them additional questions but did not get any answer for more than week so I'll update when I get it.

Comment: @tukan I understand what you are suggesting, I am trying to let you know that it cannot work to create them yourself.  It could only work if you were in charge of the server and also configured it to not use DH for exchange.  You cannot have dropbox create them as the first layer of encryption is the ssl connection to their server, which isn't going to be decryptable unless they export session keys to a log file during the session, which they would never do.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on linux it is quite easy.  During the sync process you can do:

`find $HOME/dropbox_sync_dir -type f -exec dropbox.py file status -a '{}' \; | grep 'syncing'`

**Explaining details:**

- `find <path> -type f -exec dropbox.py ... '{}' \;`

Runs `dropbox.py`  on every file or below the current directory.

> Notice that the braces are enclosed in single quote marks to protect
>   them from interpretation as shell script punctuation. The semicolon is
>   similarly protected by the use of a backslash, though single quotes
>   could have been used in that case also.

More on [man find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) pages

- `dropbox.py file status -a` from the [dropbox linux client manual](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/linux-commands):

  ```
  dropbox file status  [-l] [-a] [FILE]…

  Prints the current status of each FILE.

    Options:

     -l or --list prints out information in a format similar to the native Linux command ls.
     -a or --all do not ignore entries starting with "."
  ```

  Aliases include stat.
- `| grep 'syncing'`

Searches for the 'syncing' string.

Note: that the .py end should not be mandatory there should be an alias so writing just `dropbox` should be enough.

**First Edit** - re-edit due to Paul's comment about dropboxd (daemon) vs. dropbox.py.

### This remains the most probable way to find out what is being transferred.

I'll try to debug it myself when I finish my pending tasks.

The `dropbox.py` should be debugged via `pdb` (the python debugger) for more at [python debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).

Finally after the Paul's comments I understood where is the core of the issue.  He wants to see the *currently accessed file* or even better *the one being transferred* by the dropbox sync client.

- You could find all files used by the dropbox client currently used:

  ```
  ls -thal /proc/`pgrep dropbox`/fd | egrep -v 'socket:|pipe:|anon_inode|/dev/'
  ```
- If you can not see anything that means that something is probably
  wrong with the client.  I would recommend performing [strace](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples).

  ```
  To monitor your dropboxd script with output save into output.txt file:
  `strace -o output.txt dropboxd`

  To monitor only system calls you could enter:
  `strace -e open dropboxd`
  ```
- If you want to go even deeper you could attach an *debugger* e.g.
  `gdb` to your `strace` session.

  If you are unfamiliar with this process you can check,for example, this nice [post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-strace.html) about unix `strace` and `gdb`.

**Just a quick help:**

When you start your trace with: `strace dropboxd` (running pid would be 501)
Then you attach to it the following way:

```
$ gdb --quiet
(gdb) attach 501
```

- If everything else fails you can use other ways to sync your dropbox:

For example, use a different cli client like [dbxcli](https://github.com/dropbox/dbxcli).

**Second Edit & Forth Edit** - will not work till dropbox supports own private keys.

### Answer from the dropbox support:

**Dropbox does not support the creation of your own private keys.**

It occurred to me that it should be possible to check what is transferred even via network monitoring tool like `wireshark`.

Since the dropbox client is using SSL/TSL (or AES) [The dropbox security architecture](https://www.dropbox.com/business/trust/security/architecture) and you should have the key to check.

For details how to use `wireshare` you could check `https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL` or adjust this example to your case [Analyze SSL/TLS Client Hello Traffic](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Wireshark/HTTPS#Activity_4_-_Analyze_SSL.2FTLS_Client_Hello_Traffic).  In you have dropbox certificate you could import it into wireshark to see what is happening. (For dropbox security details you can check [Dropbox security whitepaper](https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/business/resources/dfb_security_whitepaper-vfllunodj.pdf).

**Third Edit & Forth edit** - details about the SSL/TSL decryption. (will not work till dropbox supports own private keys.)

### Answer from the dropbox support:

**Dropbox does not support the creation of your own private keys.**

In the second edit section I suggested that you can view the SSL traffic via wireshark.  Since Paul has thought that I'm suggesting that you should actually hack the `DH key exchange`, which is with current knowledge not possible, I would like to rectify it.

What I'm trying to suggest is that if you are using [dropbox business RSA](https://www.dropbox.com/business/app-integrations/RSA) and RSA authentication, you could try to use the `dropboxd with RSA key` (the daemon dropboxd is closed source, I can not check the source code if the functionality is there and probably the best solution is to ask dropbox.com directly).

If that is possible, only then import the `RSA key` to [wireshark](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116557) to see what is currently being transferred.

Comment: This approach lists all the files queued for printing, not the actual file currently being synced.

Comment: @Paul: if you do `dropbox filestatus /path_to/file` what does it return?

Comment: pick any file from your synced dir.

Comment: If you have 1000 files queued to sync, then the filestatus for each of them will be `syncing`.

Comment: @Paul ah, finally the core of your comment.  Sorry, for being dense.  I understood your question differently.  I'll edit my post for better answer.

Comment: Hah, no worries. Your current answer is actually pretty good, but for a more straightforward question. It is worth leaving the bulk of it and adding to it if you have a way to get to the "right now" files.

Comment: @Paul: I have now edited your answer, maybe now you can get the information you need.  However, using the dropbox sync client is rather tricky they do not offer such functionality first hand so you have to go via system or debug the application itself.

Comment: Note in my question, checking the /proc/xxx/fd does show the currently open files, but does not reveal the files being transferred.  No doubt there is a intermediate step to work on the file so the real file is not open at transfer time.  Also, debugging `dropbox.py` is unlikely to reveal anything, but debugging dropboxd may well (but I get your point)

Comment: @Paul: ah, wrote python.py... well that would require python debugger - of course dropboxd there.  If the fd does not show files being transfer then strace/debugging is the only way because you need to know what is `hanging` there.  I'm glad you get my point .].  One other way would be if anything is transferred would be to use wireshark and you could capture your SSL trafic and try to code it via e.g. OpenSSL - for more you could check - https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL.